# Problem using Django admin Actions with intermediate pages

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-templates

I added an admin action `send_EMAIL` through **admin.py**. When admin uses the `send_EMAIL` action for selected users I want it to show an intermediate page with all selected users and ask for confirmation. In my case, it asks for confirmation but when I click on the "send Email" button nothing happens, and I get returned to the change_list view without the `send_EMAIL` action getting called.

**Admin.py**

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', staff]
    list_filter = ['groups', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active']
    actions = ['send_EMAIL']

    
    def send_EMAIL(self, request, queryset):
        from django.core.mail import send_mail
        if 'apply' in request.POST:
            for i in queryset:
                if i.email:
                    send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',[i.email], fail_silently=False)
                else:
            self.message_user(request, "Mail sent successfully ")
        else:
            from django.http import HttpResponse
            from django.template import RequestContext, loader
            t = loader.get_template('admin/send_mail.html')
            c = RequestContext(request, {'articles': queryset})
            return HttpResponse(t.render(c),)
            
    
    
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

**templates/send_mail.html**

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block content %}


<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

    <p>The mail will be send to following users:</p>

    <ul>{{ articles|unordered_list }}</ul>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_EMAIL" />
    <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Send Email" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Where is `queryset` coming from? What is the urlconf entry for this?

Comment: I refer http://www.jpichon.net/blog/2010/08/django-admin-actions-and-intermediate-pages/) for implementing intermediate pages>I really dont know much about Django so i posted this question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found an easy way to do it. It worked for me... I hope it helps:

What you need to do is to "pass" the selected items to the confirmation page and include them in the form as well as including the `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="admin_action" />` so that django admin knows that it should still call an `admin action`. The `post` is just to know whether to process the query set or render the confirmation page.

```
# Write your admin action.
# IMPORTANT: Note the context passed to TemplateResponse

from django.contrib.admin import helpers
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def admin_action(self, request, queryset):
        if request.POST.get('post'):
            # process the queryset here
        else:
            context = {
                'title': _("Are you sure?"),
                'queryset': queryset,
                'action_checkbox_name': helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME,
            }
            return TemplateResponse(request, 'path/to/template.html',
                context, current_app=self.admin_site.name)

# The template
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n l10n %}

{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <p>The following videos will be accepted:</p>

    <ul>{{ queryset|unordered_list }}</ul>

    <div>
    {% for obj in queryset %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ action_checkbox_name }}" value="{{ obj.pk|unlocalize }}" />
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="admin_action" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post" value="yes" />
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Yes, I'm sure" %}" />
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This {% for obj in queryset %} stuff works. But to me it is Dark Magic. Anyone know WHY it works?

Comment: It's adding a hidden form input listing all the objects you intend to change.

Comment: What's Dark Magic is why it works for the first page without it.

Comment: Got it! I was using `request.POST.getlist(admin.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)` which gets only the 100 items selected on the page. Queryset sees that the "select all" choice was made.

Comment: obj.pk|unlocalize is giving an error: django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'unlocalize'