# django admin panel add a confirmation window

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I need to add a confirmation window on admin change model submit "save". Smth like this: "Do you really want to apply changes? Yes/No". I need it only for one model and only if the changed model satisfy the other conditions. I can`t override django template for one model cause of using django-admin-tool. How can i do this ?

Comment: This might help [http://stackoverflow.com/a/10219127/3279554]